# Sort the integer list first and then sort by divisible by 10 in java 8

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, comparator

I have arraylist containing {3,10,17,9,20,15,40,30, 55} so I want to sort this method so that all the divisible by 10 values are come in last in sorted list aftet the sorting the list. 
i.e. o/p should be like this : {3, 9, 15, 17, 55, 10, 20, 30, 40}

I have tried with below code but a I am not able to successfully sort out this list,

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3,10,17,9,20,55,40,30);

list.stream().sorted(((Comparator<Integer>) (v1, v2) -> Integer.compare(v1, v2))).sorted((Comparator<Integer>) (v1, v2) -> v1 % 10 == 0 ? 0 : -1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

output of above code is:
55
17
9
3
10
20
30
40

Thanks,

Comment: your comparator is not symmetric, ie 30>31 as you wanted but 31>30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to know.

First, grouping by a particular predicate when sorting is quiet easy when you know that `Boolean` values are comparable since Java 5. So you can use

```
Comparator.comparing(i -> i%10==0)
```

to sort numbers dividable by ten to the end.

Second, you can chain comparators using `thenComparing`, so that elements being equal according to the first comparator will be sorted according to the next one.

Together, the operation becomes

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3,10,17,9,20,55,40,30);

list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> i%10==0)
                      .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that the complete operation requires an explicitly typed parameter for the first lambda expression (`(Integer i)`) due to limitations in the type inference.

You could also write

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> i%10==0)
                      .thenComparingInt(i -> i))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

though, I prefer reusing the already existing comparator `Comparator.naturalOrder()` when applicable.

Comment: I was trying this only, I was not aware about Boolean value are comparable. Thanks once again.

Comment: Nice answer, +1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to logically divide the numbers into two groups and sort each group separately.

You can either split the list based on the division by 10 criteria, and perform the sort on the 2 sub-lists separately, or you can achieve the same result with a single `Comparator` that checks whether the 2 compared numbers belong to the same group:

- if they don't, determine which should come first based on the group
- if they do, compare them within their group by their value

  ```
  list.stream()
      .sorted((v1, v2) -> {
                  if (v1 % 10 == 0) {
                      if (v2 % 10 == 0)
                          return Integer.compare(v1, v2); // both are divisible by 10 
                                                          // sort by value
                      else
                          return 1; // only v1 is divisible by 10, should come after v2
                  } else {
                      if (v2 % 10 != 0)
                          return Integer.compare(v1, v2); // both are not divisible by 10
                                                          // sort by value
                      else
                          return -1; // only v2 is divisible by 10, should come after v1
                  }

          })
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

Output:

```
3
9
17
55
10
20
30
40
```

Comment: Yes I prefer the way you've set this out to the way I have it. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Well to achieve this you need to:

- First divide the list into two lists, one with numbers divisible by
  `10` and the second with those who aren't.
- Then just sort them separately
- And finally append the first to second one.

This is how should be your code:

```
List<Integer> dividedBy10 = list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p % 10 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(dividedBy10);

List<Integer> others = list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p % 10 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(others);

//Then append the first list to the sorted one
others.addAll(dividedBy10);
```

**Edit:**

Or like [@yahya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6365112/yahya) suggested you can just sort your original list, then filter it into lists and append these two lists later:

```
Collections.sort(list);

List<Integer> dividedBy10 = list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p % 10 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> others = list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p % 10 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
others.addAll(dividedBy10);
```

Comment: If ya sort the original list, won't that save your two sorts later? But however I like the idea and gave ya plus one  though :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are negating the numbers that are not divisible by 10 as a hack to get them out first. But that will reverse the order of those numbers, which accounts for your output!

You need to be more careful when comparing the divisible by 10 numbers, so the comparator ranks them lower than other numbers. Something like this will work:

```
list.stream().sorted(((Comparator<Integer>) (v1, v2) -> {
    if (v1 % 10 == 0 && v2 % 10 == 0) {
        return Integer.compare(v1, v2);
    } else if (v1 % 10 == 0) {
        // v2 is effectively larger
        return -1;
    } else if (v2 % 10 == 0) {
        // v1 is effectively larger
        return 1;
    }
    return Integer.compare(v1, v2);
}))/*etc*/
```

Comment: @davidxxx:: Absolutely not. You want to preserve the ascending order of the subsections.

Comment: My gosh. I though that it was that he would get. Really not good read the question. Sorry Bathsheba.

Answer (score 0):

A single sort is required :

```
list.stream().sorted(((Comparator<Integer>) (v1, v2) -> {

    // if both are divisible by 10, you sort them with their order natural
    if (v1 % 10 == 0 && v2 % 10 == 0) {
       return Integer.compare(v1, v2);
    }

    // if only the first argument is divisible by 10, it is always at the end
    else if (v1 % 10 == 0) {
      return 1;
    }       

    // if only the second argument is divisible by 10, it is always at the end
    else if (v2 % 10 == 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // in other cases, you sort by natural order
    return Integer.compare(v1, v2);
}))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is the output :

> 3 9 17 55 10 20 30 40

Comment: But this doesn't sort the numbers that are divisible by 10 correctly. E.g. the both divisible by 10 case should call the normal .compare

Comment: @Bathsheba Really sorry. I have really bad read the question.

Comment: no worries. By the way, we differ in our specific return 1 and return -1 cases. Who's right? ;-) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

```
(a,b) -> (a<b?-1:a==b?0:1) + (a%10==0?2:0) - (b%10==0?2:0)
```

How this works:

`(a<b?-1:a==b?0:1)` normally compares the integers (Has a weight of 1)

`+ (a%10==0?2:0)` Checks if the first integer is divisible by 10 (Has a weight of 2)

`- (b%10==0?2:0)` Checks if the second integer is divisible by 10 (Has a weight of 2)

---

As long as `Integer.compare` only returns -1,0,1 you could use this (But as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) points out there is no guaranty)

```
(a,b) -> Integer.compare(a, b) + (a%10==0?2:0) - (b%10==0?2:0)
```

Comment: There is no guaranty that the value returned by `Integer.compare(a, b)` “has a weight of 1”.

Comment: Look at the [source of Integer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l1233) the method compere(int,int) only returns 0,1,-1.

Comment: This is the source code of one particular implementation. If the documentation doesn’t say that it is guaranteed to get only `0`,`1`, and `-1`, then it isn’t guaranteed. So the implementation can change at any time. Or the JVM might replace calls of this method with an intrinsic CPU instruction, not necessarily returning only one of these three values. And [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) clearly says “0; …less than 0;… and greater than 0”. If they wanted to say that the magnitude is either zero or one, they did it.

Comment: You could use `Integer.signum(Integer.compare(a, b))`, that would be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You only have three return values:

- `Integer.compare(a, b)` if both values are divisible by 10 and when they are not
- `> 0` if first value is divisible by 10
- `< 0` else

---

```
list.sort((a, b) -> {
  if ((a % 10 == 0) == (b % 10 == 0)) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
  } else {
    return a % 10 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

Or if you prefer non readable code

```
list.sort((a, b) -> (a % 10 == 0) == (b % 10 == 0) ? a.compareTo(b) : a % 10 == 0 ? 1 : -1);
```